# do we need to explicitly case type when converting?

Tags: swift

when I read the doc of swift 
https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html

```
let anotherPi = 3 + 0.14159
// anotherPi is also inferred to be of type Double
```

this works, however if I delete the "Double" in the following case, it does not work.

```
let three = 3
let pointOneFourOneFiveNine = 0.14159
let pi = Double(three) + pointOneFourOneFiveNine
```

May I ask why do we need to explicitly convert the type in second case? what is the difference?

Answer (score 0):

It is because of Swift's automatic type inference.

```
let three = 3 // Here **three** is inferred as Int 
let pointOneFourOneFiveNine = 0.14159  // Here **pointOneFourOneFiveNine** is inferred as Double 
let pi = Double(three) + pointOneFourOneFiveNine
```

And since you cannot add a `Double` to an `Int`, it’s the reason that you have to wrap the **three** as `Double(three)`.

```
let anotherPi = 3 + 0.14159
// anotherPi is also inferred to be of type Double
```

The reason the above code works because the compiler finds that both the summing inputs can be represented as `Double`, so it assigns the type `Double` to **anotherPi**. Hope this clears your doubt.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I want to ask why the first case works then?
    let anotherPi = 3 + 0.14159
 3 is also integer but in this case no error

Comment: @FrankieWong check if this helps. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51429599/7734643

Comment: @FrankieWong pls refer to the updated answer

Comment: Thank you @RakeshaShastri
So if if is integer literal like  3 + 0.14159, then swift can inferred to be of type Double. But if it is integer variable, we have to do explicit cast, right?

Comment: @FrankieWong correct :)